# "arco da velha" - que arco? que velha?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, origem

**Qual é a origem da expressão "coisas do arco da velha"?**  Onde teria se originado e a que se refere?  Minha pesquisa a respeito mostrou resultados inconsistentes: alguns autores sugerem que o arco em questão é o arco-íris. Outros dizem ser a respeito uma arca, um baú, e não um arco.

A expressão ainda é bem usada em pt-BR por indivíduos de meia idade e da terceira idade, mas nunca ouvi um jovem usá-la. Significa "fatos ou coisas incríveis, que o ouvinte não imagina ou que ficaria surpreso se soubesse"
exemplo:

- "Ela me contou coisas do arco da velha."
- "Quando jovem, ele fazia coisas do arco da velha"

Nunca ouvi algum falante de pt-PT usá-la. Não sei se é de uso corrente em Portugal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usa-se [***coisas do arco da velha*** (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/arco-da-velha)  em Portugal com o mesmo significado que no Brasil. E ***arco da velha*** era o nome que eu usava em criança, antes de aprender o nome ‘mais culto’ *arco-íris*. E sempre interpretei o *arco* das *coisas do arco da velha* como o arco-íris, por podermos poeticamente ver o arco-íris como uma manifestação fabulosa, inalcançável, como as coisas dos contos de fadas.

Interpretações pessoais à parte, *arco da velha* foi durante séculos a nome popular mais comum do arco-íris. E teve associado a si lendas fantásticas que justificam a expressão *coisas do arco da velha*. O dicionário Houaiss assinala a ocorrência de *arco da velha* em 1563 em *Imagem da Vida Christam* do Frei Hector Pinto. Curiosamente eu encontrei uma ocorrência do ano anterior, no  [*Dicionário de Português-Latim 1* de Jerónimo Cardoso, 1562, p. 18 (fac simile do original; vale a pena ver):](http://purl.pt/15192/3/#/36)

> Arco da Velha * Arcus Coelestis

Entretanto o Frei Hector Pinto, citado em por Rafael Bluteau no seu *Vocabulario portuguez e latino* (1712-21), explica que *velha* é um encurtamento de *Lei velha*, ou Antigo Testamento ([Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/); ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> Arco celeste, ou (como diz o vulgo) ***Arco da velha***. Diz Fr. Hector Pinto, que os Portuguezes lhes deraõ este nome, porque na Ley velha disse Deos, que nas nuvens poria este Arco por sinal de paz entre si, & os homens. Os cultos lhe chamaõ Iris.

Ou seja, o *arco da velha* seria o arco da Lei velha. O Frei Heitor Pinto refere-se à promessa que, segundo o Antigo Testamento, Deus fez a Noé depois do Dilúvio de não mais destruir o mundo com água (Genesis, 9:12-16). Também se usou *arco das velhas*, que Frei Heitor Pinto interpreta como «arco em que falam as velhas escripturas» [(*Imagem da Vida Christam*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=eS9MAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA300&dq=%22arco%20das%20velhas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXsbKSkeHLAhVGwBQKHYPhAQ0Q6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22arco%20das%20velhas%22&f=false).

O filólogo brasileiro João Ribeiro (*Frases Feitas: Estudo conjetural de locuções, ditados e provérbios*, 1908-9; [acesso integral a uma edição de 2009](http://www.academia.org.br/sites/default/files/publicacoes/arquivos/frases_feitas_-_joao_ribeiro_-para_internet.pdf)) acha esta sugestão engenhosa, mas não lhe dá grande crédito, porque, entre outras razões, escreve ele, «desde muito se apegou a expressão bem ou mal à história de uma velha feiticeira na linguagem e no floclore peninsular» (p. 157). Acha ele que a ideia do *arco da velha* vem das costas arqueadas dos idosos. Segundo ele, esta origem explicaria outros nomes do arco, o *arcumbé* veneziano e o *corcubéu* rumão, e ainda várias lendas e tradições associadas ao arco da velha.

Leite Vasconcellos [(*Tradições Populares de Portugal*, 1882, p. 58-9)](https://archive.org/stream/tradiespopulare00vascgoog#page/n77/mode/2up/search/velha) também diz que a «palavra *Velha* nas nossas tradições é possível que substitua uma qualquer entidade mythica», e observa que no norte de Portugal, quando o dia amanhece com muita geada se costuma dizer: «Ah! A *Velha* esta noite peneirou bem!» Relata ainda que nalguns sítios se diz que o *arco da velha* mergulha nos rios para beber água, que onde ele pousa está uma *Velha* a coser, noutros sítios, que aparece um pinto de prata.

Luís da Câmara Cascudo [(Dicionário do Folclore Brasileiro, 1954, p. 101-2)](http://www.slideshare.net/edgararruda/dicionario-do-folclore-brasileiro-camara-cascudo) confirma a existência no Brasil desta crença de o arco íris mergulhar nos rios para beber água; nalguns sítios acrescenta-se que ele engole crianças que por lá andem. Cascudo fala ainda de várias outras lendas associadas ao arco-íris no Brasil (segundo ele, no Brasil o nome *arco da velha* é comum apenas no sul), e diz que este tipo de lendas é comum em todo o mundo.

Não é portanto de espantar que *coisas do arco da velha* sejam coisas fantásticas. A ocorrência mais antiga que encontrei de *coisas do arco da velha* é de 1845, numa carta assinada por «*Uma Obscura Portuense*» e publicada na [Revista Universal Lisbonense, Tomo IV, p. 552 (fac simile do original):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=o7wGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA552&dq=%22coisas%20do%20arco%20da%20velha%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi544bcp9zLAhXM1B4KHUnUArg4FBDoAQg2MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22coisas%20do%20arco%20da%20velha%22&f=false)

> O feiticeiro que foi preso em Monte-mór-o-novo e que se dizia do concelho de Bouças [Matosinhos], será acaso discípulo de duas desembruchadeiras, que segundo se me conta, fazem em Bouças ***coisas do arco da velha?***

A expressão ocorre com frequência no Google books a partir dessa data. Não encontrei qualquer referência a *coisas da arca da velha* (ou *a cousas*). Acho portanto que podemos pôr essa hipótese de lado.

Comment: Adorei a resposta!

Answer (score -1):

Ao assistir o vídeo a seguir sobre a origem do nome Portugal, me deparei com a citação do "arco da velha". Ao buscar o significado, me deparei com essa consulta e resposta. Creio que possa ajudar.
https://youtu.be/PvGQhBfo2OM

Comment: Arnaldo, bem-vindo à comunidade. O vídeo sugere uma explicação de se chamar "arco da velha" ao arco-íris, mas seria melhor explicares isso na resposta, não simplesmente indicar o vídeo. Ainda por cima é preciso chegar ao minuto 8 ou 9 para ele começar a valar disso.

Comment: Bim-vindo ao Portuguese SE, Arnaldo! É importante que as postagens sejam autocontidas, que contenham a informação necessária — links externos devem ser opcionais, e isso é especialmente importante no caso de fontes relativamente efêmeras como vídeos do Youtube.